# Answering opinion based questions....

Tags: discussion

For questions in which the requester is asking for an opinion, such [as this one](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/1334/pre-drawing-cards-or-tiles), is it permissible to add your opinion even if it's similar or identical to another answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's very similar or identical, then no - upvote the relevant answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you think you can write a similar yet better answer, by all means - go for it!  The community will judge the two similar answers over time.  Eventually (after a month+), it might be nice if the owner of the more unpopular answer deleted it, but that isn't necessary.

You can also edit another answer if you think that it just needs a little enhancement.  For example:

- Add an explanatory link
- Reword an awkward statement
- Fix spelling